# JQuery DatePicker UI display format

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using JQuery DatePicker on my project and it's very effective except its actual layout on the screen. I'm limiting the date range to 60 days and therefore obviously limiting the calendar to 4 months. The problem is that it is being displayed length ways and goes outside of the browser so I was wondering if there was a way to actually change the display from:

Month | Month | Month | Month

to

Month | Month

Month | Month

Here's what code I'm using at the moment:

```
$(function(){
    $('#dp').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yymmdd',
        numberOfMonths: 4,
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: 60,
    });
    $('#date').on('click', function() {
        $('#dp').datepicker('show');            
    });
    $("#dp").change(function() {
        var tempDate = $('#dp').datepicker('getDate');
        var newformattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('D d M yy', tempDate);
        $("#showDate").html(newformattedDate);
        $(".eventDate").addClass('eventAdded dateProvided');
    });
});
```

Comment: can u set up a fiddle!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look at the [documentation for `numberOfMonths`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-numberOfMonths):

> **numberOfMonths**
>
> - Type: `Number` or `Array`
> - Default: `1`
>
> The number of months to show at once. Multiple types supported:
>
> - `Number`: The number of months to display in a single row.
> - `Array`: An array defining the number of rows and columns to display.
>
> Code examples:
>
> Initialize the datepicker with the numberOfMonths option specified:
>
> ```
> $( ".selector" ).datepicker({ numberOfMonths: [ 2, 3 ] });
> ```